# Workflow showing error when i click to start “Something went wrong. To try again, reload the page and then start the workflow”

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

When i click to start the workflow show alert "Something went wrong. To try again, reload the page and then start the workflow" after that nothing happen..

It's happen only for my old workflows when i create new workflow it works.

I tried -restart service bus message broker 
        -restart service bus gateway 
        -recycle workflowMgntpool 
        -flushed the dsn resolver cache 
        -restart  WorkflowServiceBackend

and the problem still occurs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try

- Remove workflow proxy from Central Admin --> Services
- Register Workflow Service again using PowerShell, it will create a new proxy or most probably let you know the error
- Don't forget to check service associations once the PowerShell command is executed

Comment: I had the same issue but is solved now. The issue was with the certificate used while configuring the workflow manager So what i did is to:
1- open the config wizard, and select to leave the farm
2- delete all the 6 databases related to the workflow manager
3- once done, reopen the workflow manager again and select to "Auto Generate certificates" and provide a password
4- proceed with the installation and retest your workflow. should be working ;)